# How to upload string to ftp with flysystem and utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, ftp, flysystem

I have a task to upload a txt file to the FTP server using `League\Flysystem` with `UTF-8`

Code which is responsible for that is looking like this:

```php
...
use League\Flysystem\FilesystemInterface;

final class UploadToFTPHandler implements CommandHandlerInterface
{
    private FilesystemInterface $filesystem;

    public function __construct(FilesystemInterface $ftpFilesystem)
    {
        $this->filesystem = $ftpFilesystem;
    }

    public function __invoke(UploadToFTP $command): void
    {
        $fileContents = 'którzy uczestniczyć w procesie o stary zamek, niegdyś własność';
        $fileContents = mb_convert_encoding($fileContents, 'UTF-8');

        $this->filesystem->write(
            sprintf('%s.txt', uniqid()),
            $fileContents,
            ['mimetype' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8']
        );
    }
}
```

After uploading this file, when I open it on my server, it looks like this:

```
kt&oacute;rzy uczestniczyÄ‡&nbsp;w procesie o stary zamek,&nbsp;niegdyĹ› wĹ‚asnoĹ›Ä‡
```

As you can see, there is no utf-8 encoding despite that I have set `['mimetype' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8']` and `mb_convert_encoding($fileContents, 'UTF-8')`

What I am doing wrong to achieve correct `UTF-8` encoding?

Implementation of this method `$this->filesystem->write` is [here](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/f3ad69181b8afed2c9edf7be5a2918144ff4ea32/src/Adapter/Ftp.php#L248)